# Omission from Koteret to Hil. Talmud Torah

Tags: torah-study, rambam, mitzvah

The Rambam wrote small introductions to sections of Mishna Torah called a [Koteret](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57637/source-of-koteret). In the introduction to Hilchos Talmud Torah he [writes](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/1300.htm):

> יש בכללן שתי מצוות עשה--(א) ללמוד תורה; (ב) לכבד מלמדיה ויודעיה.  וביאור שתי מצוות אלו בפרקים אלו.

A Mitzvah to learn Torah and a Mitzvah to honor those who learn it and know it.

In the Minyan Hamitzvot Hakatzar , however, he lists, as the [11th positive commandment](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Positive_Mitzvot.11?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all):

> (לִלְמֹד תּוֹרָה **וּלְלַמְּדָהּ**, שֶׁנֶּאֱמָר: "וְשִׁנַּנְתָּם לְבָנֶיךָ" (דברים ו, ז.
>
> To learn Torah **and teach it**, as is said: "And you shall teach your children" (Deut. 6:7)

Why does Rambam omit the obligation to *teach* Torah from the Koteret to Hilchos Talmud Torah, when he includes it in the associated Mitzvah listing? He could have easily included "וּלְלַמְּדָהּ" in the Koteret as well.

Comment: @mevaqesh, off the cuff speculation - because teaching only applies to a father of a son or a חכם, whereas learning applies more broadly.

Comment: @Yishai not sure I can agree with your speculation. The process of talmud torah is intrinsically "lilmod al manas lilamed." There's a gemara in chagigah discussing hakhel that explains that "lima'an yilmidu" exempts the mute because they CANNOT TEACH (even though they can learn).

Comment: I'll bet that it has something to do with the learning and teaching being intrinsically intertwined, as indicated by the Halachot first describing an obligation to teach and then going into "and if you haven't been taught, you have to teach yourself." That doesn't really explain either the omission or the discrepancy, but it's probably part of the conceptual framework that does.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, maybe, but כל הראוי לבילה אין בילה מעקבת בו. The fact that the potential to teach is required doesn't obligate everyone who knows only one Halacha to teach it. The Rambam, at any rate, doesn't make such a requirement.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, note also that an אילם is not listed in Hilchos Talmud Torah as potur.

Comment: In spite of what you say, you are not quoting from _Sefer ha-Mitzvot_ ([there](http://www.daat.ac.il/DAAT/mahshevt/hamitsvot/ase1-2.htm) it says, in R Yosef Qafih's translation: "המצווה הי"א
היא הציווי שנצטווינו ללמד חכמת התורה וללמדה - וזהו הנקרא: תלמוד תורה,
והוא אמרו 'ושיננתם לבניך'"), but from the list of _Mitsvot Aseh_ in the preface to the _Mishneh Torah_ (like [here](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/0001.htm#11)).

Comment: @TamirEvan fine so I was using an old sefer hamitzvos. Nevertheless the contradiction remains, for even in the Qafih sefer hamitzvos there is still one mitzva to learn and do teach. This is abundantly clear in the מנין מצות הקצר  even in the Qafih ed. who has: ללמוד תורה וללמדה, שנאמר "ושיננתם לבניך".

Comment: (1) No, what you are quoting is from the list of _Mitzvot Aseh_ in the preface to the _Mishneh Torah_. Effectively, what you are asking is why in one listing of the _Mitzvah_ he omits something he mentions in another, in the same book. This is not a conflict between _Sefer ha-Mitzvot_ and the _Mishneh Torah_, as your question suggests. (By the way, check again: you're linking to the list of _Mitzvot Aseh_ in the preface to the _Mishneh Torah_, not an old _Sefer ha-Mitzvot_.) (2) What are you referring to, when you say "מנין מצות הקצר"?

Comment: @TamirEvan okay we were miscommunication. the listing at the end of the intro to MT is commonly called the מנין מצות הקצר. The contradiction was from there to the koteret. His opinion in מנין הקצר is the same as that which you quoted from the R. Qafih ed; that there is one mitzva comprising study and teaching. (BTW I goofed about the Qafih girsa of the מנין הקצר as I was merely citing the mekhon mamre text).

Comment: (1) O.K., but you called it "Sefer Hamitzvos" in your question, not "מנין מצות הקצר", which prompted my original comment. Looking at the edit history, I did misspeak when saying that you are claiming to quote from "Sefer Hamitzvos", when it wasn't you who did the quoting. (2) When I made my original comment, I was of the opinion that a discrepancy between between two listings of the _Mitzvah_ in the same book, was less significant than in two different books, as the author could have relied on his more exact wording in one place, and been less careful in another.

Answer (score 1):

I heard from R' Moshe Einstadter that the purpose of the Koteres is to define the nature of the *mitzvah*, as opposed to describing how to fulfill the *mitzvah*, which is what the halachos listed under each category proceed to do.  If my memory serves me correctly, he even used this as an example, and explained that the definition of the *mitzvah* is to learn Torah, and one aspect of the *performance* of the *mitzvah*, the מעשה מצוה as R' Einstadter put it, is teaching, which is included in the very beginning of the halachos of this topic.

Comment: Fascinating. If you could clarify this point with him I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: (1) Why then did he add "וללמדה" where he did? (2) Also (not mentioned in the question), when he listed the _Mitzvot_ according to the division into books (at the end of the intro), he omitted "וללמדה" [there](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/0003.htm#13) too. There, he doesn't have _Halakhot_ or anything to elaborate the performance of the _Mitzvah_. Why omit it there also?

Comment: @mevaqesh which point needs clarification? I speak to him occasionally and could ask.

Comment: @jim If he indeed applied this to this Rambam, and if so, how exactly.